# Trying to set keyboard layout using Xorg configuration but it's not working

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to set my HP Pavilion g6 keyboard layout to English(us) and Arabic(ara).

I'm using Fedora 18, but followed [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_keyboard_layouts_in_X) anyways.

Here's my `90-keyboard-layout.conf` file :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver          "evdev"
        Option          "XkbModel"  "pc105"
        Option          "XkbLayout"     "us,ara(qwerty_digits)"
        Option          "XkbVariant"    "qwerty_digits,qwerty_digits"
        Option          "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

I've entered `pc105` because I have no idea what's the corresponding `XkbModel` for my HP Pavilion g6 keyboard (looked in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg` but didn't find it).

I have also this file `00-anaconda-keyboard.conf` which contains :

```
#This file was generated by the Anaconda installer
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option          "XkbOptions"    "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option  "DontZap" "false"
EndSection
```

Here's my `setxkbmap -print`:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(qwerty_digits)+ara(qwerty_digits)(qwerty_digits):2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

What else is missing? Layout switching is not working at all so far.

Comment: @don_crissti I'm not using DE, i'm using Awesome Window Manager only.

Comment: @don_crissti wow worked like a charm ! The whole problem was with the first `xkbvariant` it was unnecessary. Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `90-keyboard-layout.conf` like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver          "evdev"
        Option          "XkbModel"      "evdev"
        Option          "XkbLayout"     "us,ara"
        Option          "XkbVariant"    ",qwerty_digits"
        Option          "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```